# getting error after disabling keycloak login redirection spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

i'm blocked in my development after deactivating the keycloak login redirection in my Security config for my api gateway because i want to use keycloak only inside my user microservice, after adding :

`http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/form-login"))`

i'm getting this error :

```
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
```

Here my serviceConfig class

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/css/**","/contact-us","/actuator/**","/isalive/**",
                                "/api/v1/auth/**","/login", "/signup", "/publicOffers")))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/form-login"))
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    private Converter<Jwt, Mono<AbstractAuthenticationToken>> grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {
        GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor extractor = new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor();
        return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(extractor);
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());

    }


    static class GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor extends JwtAuthenticationConverter {

        @Override
        protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {
            Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
            JSONObject realmAccess = (JSONObject) claims.get("realm_access");
            if(realmAccess!=null){
                JSONArray roles = (JSONArray) realmAccess.get("roles");

                return roles.stream()
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

and my application.propeties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/myrealm
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-id=SpringTest-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-secret=E9Pk0mgRYThmvaq9wt38Spi7jpzkoc8l
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/myrealm
```

i would like to know how to fix this and how can i change the authenticationManager bean that was probably provided by spring.security.oauth2.client

Answer (score 0):

if anybody have the same issue you can just add this to fix your problem with adding a custom **ReactiveAuthenticationManager** to your authentication.

```
    http.authenticationManager(new ReactiveAuthenticationManager() {
        @Override
        public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```